# angularjs Firebase Databse filtering using equalTo and passing an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to filter my output of DatabaseONE by values of a child of another DatabaseTWO:

```
var myquery = DatabaseRef.ref("mydatabaseONE").orderByKey().equalTo("-KUTPrs6ARZXjbjtNr7O");
$scope.mylist = $firebaseArray(myquery);
```

For my second database, I have set up this service to get the keys and values of the child (i.e. books) I am querying in the DatabaseTWO:

```
app.service('MyUser', ['DatabaseRef', 'firebase', function(DatabaseRef, firebase) {
    var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        userbooks: function() {
            return(
                DatabaseRef.ref('/users/' + userId).once('value')
                    .then(function onSuccess(snapshot) {
                        return snapshot.val().books;
                    })
            );
        }
```

and the result is like this when I call it like below and console log it :

```
var mybooks = MyUser.userbooks();
```

[image]

My question is how can I pass the values of my DatabaseTWO promise value object into the first query using DatabaseONE and put it as an array in `equalTo` ? As you can see, I have manually inserted one example value, and it works, but I want to put all three of them (marked in red) as an array?
Or if you have any other creative ideas to filter using `equalTo`?